# How to query MongoDB with DBRef?

Tags: mongodb

**I have MongoDB document like this**

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5ad72ebae11b7047690ec174"),
"service" : DBRef("service", ObjectId("59ddb492e11b7005e4470d04")),
"salaryCode" : DBRef("salaryCode",ObjectId("5a786c71e11b7036e60bdf4c")),
"grade" : DBRef("grade", ObjectId("59ddb2fbe11b7005e4470cf0"))}
"grade" : DBRef("grade", ObjectId("59ddb2fbe11b7005e4470cf0"))}
```

**How can I access service -> DBRef -> ObjectId with finding or remove query? I tried the following but not work:**

```
db.serviceCriteria.find({"service" :DBRef.ObjectId("5a786c71e11b7036e60bdf4c")}).pretty()
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
db.serviceCriteria.find({
  'service.$id': ObjectId("5a786c71e11b7036e60bdf4c")
})
```

or this

```
db.serviceCriteria.find({
  'service': DBRef("service", ObjectId("5a786c71e11b7036e60bdf4c"))
})
```